# Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onItemSelected in OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I am implementing spinner in Android studio. I have the below code. I am getting error `MainActivity must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) in OnItemSelectedListener`. But As you can see below, I have implemented `onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)`.

Also, when I run the code, I see error  `MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>) in OnItemSelectedListener`

What am I missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_supplychainEntities);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //stuff here to handle item selection
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

              Log.i("GTOUTOUT", "Nothing Selected");
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should choose only one way to implement OnItemSelectedListener, actually you have implemented both of the way of OnItemSelectedListener and not override the onItemSelected and onNothingSelected methods**

//**Either remove this**

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //stuff here to handle item selection
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

              Log.i("GTOUTOUT", "Nothing Selected");
            }
        });
```

**OR** REMOVE this

```
implements OnItemSelectedListener //from class statement
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it twice, you have to keep just one. Also, move your code inside your `onCreate` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_supplychainEntities);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //stuff here to handle item selection
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

              Log.i("GTOUTOUT", "Nothing Selected");
            }
        });
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the abstract functions defined in `OnItemSelectedListener` to be able to instantiate your activity class. Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_supplychainEntities);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //stuff here to handle item selection
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        Log.i("GTOUTOUT", "Nothing Selected");
    }
}
```